# How to change layout & class with arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, layout, arraylist

I want to make my class and layout change when I click on specific items. For example, if I click "physical" from the array list I want it to open up the physical java class and the physical xml layout. How do i do this? As you can see down below I have already tried with the View view and switch/case.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;        
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements         AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView listView;
private String[] planets;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    planets=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    Toast.makeText(this, planets[position] + " was selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    selectItem(position);
    selectItem2(view);
    }



public void selectItem(int position) {

    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(planets[position]);}





public void selectItem2 (View view){

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), physical_fragment.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);}}



public void setTitle(String title){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
    }
```

Comment: You expect `view.getId()` to return 0? That's probably not right. You also should have a `break` statement and a `default` case in your `switch`

Comment: Any ideas on what to change it to then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want compare the `id` of the `View` since all of the `Views` in your list will use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` they will all have the same `id`.

You may consider passing the `position` and comparing that.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(this, planets[position] + " was selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    selectItem(position);
    selectItem2(position);
}

public void selectItem2 (int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity .this,    physical_fragment.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Something like that should get you started. However, you may eventually want to check the content of the item selected such as the the actual position of the string resource then get that id in case you decide to switch around the list items or modify them in some other way.

Comment: Yes, because I didn't change that part of the answer. `view` doesn't exist in that method anymore. See the update

Comment: thank you but the app crashes when i click it. should the case and break be under my NavigationDrawerFragment.class ?

Comment: Look at the stacktrace for the error. You've got to do some debugging on your own.

Comment: lol, but im new to coding.. was i supposed to do something within the android manifest with my other classes that i have?

Comment: I don't know, depends on what you have. What does the stacktrace say?!? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: im trying to upload picture of it

Comment: You need to add `physical_fragment` as an Activity in your manifest. FYI: that's a terrible name for an Activity if that is indeed what that class is